# how to write Android Custom lint rule to forbid calling specific function in all classes that extends specific type?

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

I want to write a custom lint rule to ban calling function `states.accept()` in all classes that extends `BaseViewModel` where states is a `BehaviorRelay` object.

how can I achieve something like this.
I’ve written the check using `visitMethodCall` but this only can check the function name and if it’s member of `BehaviorRelay`,

the missing part is how to check if this function is being called in children’s of BaseViewModel.

**below** is the part that works: using `visitMethodCall` but detecting the function in whole code.

```
override fun visitMethodCall(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, method: PsiMethod) {
    val evaluator = context.evaluator
    if (evaluator.isMemberInClass(method, BEHAVIOR_RELAY)) {
        if (method.name == ACCEPT_FUNCTION) {
            context.report(
                Incident(
                    issue = ISSUE,
                    scope = node,
                    location = context.getNameLocation(node),
                    message = "View Models implements `BaseViewModel` must not update `states`"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applicableSuperClasses` will filter only the classes that extends passed types, in my case `BaseViewModel`. this function works with `visitClass`.

Then using `AbstractUastVisitor()` to visit all calls in that class and find the specific function by name, also checking if it's a member function in target type.

full working code.

```
 override fun applicableSuperClasses(): List<String>? {
        return listOf(BASE_VIEW_MODEL)
    }

    override fun visitClass(context: JavaContext, declaration: UClass) {
        val evaluator = context.evaluator

        declaration.accept(object : AbstractUastVisitor() {
            override fun visitCallExpression(node: UCallExpression): Boolean {

                val isRelayFunction = evaluator.isMemberInClass(
                    node.resolve(),
                    BEHAVIOR_RELAY
                )
                if (node.methodName == ACCEPT_FUNCTION && isRelayFunction) {
                    context.report(
                        issue = ISSUE,
                        scope = node,
                        location = context.getNameLocation(node),
                        message = "View Models implements `BaseViewModel` must not update `states`"
                    )
                }
                return super.visitCallExpression(node)
            }
        })
    }
```